# SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.ignitionfuel.org'

Tags: ros-melodic, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
 [ INFO] [1565838380.026371061]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1565838380.124697592]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1565838380.237565240]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1565838380.309446638]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1565838387.533294427, 0.038000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1565838388.437564512, 0.624000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[Err] [REST.cc:205] Error in REST request

libcurl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.ignitionfuel.org'
```

I see an answer (https://answers.ros.org/question/3212... ) saying to change in ~/.ignition/fuel/config.yaml, `api.ignitionfuel.org` to `https://api.ignitionrobotics.org`. But I think that I don't have ~/.ignition/fuel/config.yaml, because I'm looking and I don't found. Is it in some place or I need install? How?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23475/ssl:-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches-target-host-name-%27api.ignitionfuel.org%27/) by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14669/jose-araujo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-08-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a know bug affecting Ubuntu official packages which are not the latest gazebo9 releases. More information as well as possible workarounds are available in this bug report: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2607/error-restcc-205-during-startup-gazebo#comment-56048528

---

Originally posted by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) with karma: 1485 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In case this is still happening after updating to gazebo9,

Try chainging `https://api.ignitionfuel.org` to `https://fuel.ignitionrobotics.org` in `~/.ignition/fuel/config.yaml`

Reference: https://varhowto.com/how-to-fix-libcurl-51-ssl-no-alternative-certificate-subject-name-matches-target-host-name-api-ignitionfuel-org-gazebo-ubuntu-ros-melodic/

---

Originally posted by [wongrufus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21315/wongrufus/) with karma: 78 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1